# Rails 4.2 server; private and public ip not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rack, actiondispatch

I recently updated my rails 4.1.8 to 4.2

I'm not able to access rails app using private ip `192.168.1.x:3000` and also with my `public-ip address`.

Rails app is working with `lvh.me:3000`, `0.0.0.0:3000`, `localhost:3000` and `127.0.0.1:3000`. But it looks
all the the address are pointing to `127.0.0.1:3000` in my server log [rails-issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5223).

It was working fine in 4.1

I tried adding following in `environments/development.rb`, but nothing changed.

```
TRUSTED_PROXIES = %r{
  ^127\.0\.0\.1$                | # localhost
  ^(10                          | # private IP 10.x.x.x
    172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]) | # private IP in the range 172.16.0.0 .. 172.31.255.255
    192\.168                      # private IP 192.168.x.x
   )\.
}x

config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies = /^127\.0\.0\.1$/ # localhost
```

I'm trying to point my local server to public ip address. I already configured port forward to access in public address.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default host for Rails servers has changed in 4.2. It now runs on localhost, which means it'll only accept connections from the host IP. You'll need to run `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` to start your server.

Please see [the 4.2 release notes, section 3.3 for more details.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#default-host-for-rails-server)

Comment: Thanks @richard. It's working!!. I should have read properly.

Comment: is there anyway where you can make this standard with 4.2.0. its annoying to type that in every time.

Answer (score 2):

To run as public `-b` and in a specific port use `-p` :

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8520
```