# Connecting to ActionCable from iOS app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have been stuck on this all day. I have the very simple ActionCable example app (the chat app) by David Heinemeier Hansson working correctly (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0WUjGkDFS0).

I am trying to hit the websocket connection with an iPhone app. I am able to receive pings when I connect to `ws://localhost:3000/cable`, but I'm not quite sure how to subscribe to channels from outside of a javascript context.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same but without success. Which code did you used in the client IOS part?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 14):

Oh man, I went through this problem too after reading this question.

After a while, I finally found this magical Github issue page:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22675

> I do understand that this patch would break some tests. That is not
>   surprising to me. But the original issue I believe is still relevant
>   and shouldn't be closed.
>
> The following JSON sent to the server should succeed:
>
> {"command": "subscribe","identifier":{"channel":"ChangesChannel"}}
>
> It does not! Instead you must send this:
>
> {"command":
>   "subscribe","identifier":"{\"channel\":\"ChangesChannel\"}"}

I finally got the iOS app to subscribe to room channel following the Github user suggestion about Rails problem.

My setup is as follow:

- Objective C
- Using PocketSocket framework for making web socket connection
- Rails 5 RC1
- Ruby 2.2.4p230

I assume you know how to use Cocoapods to install PocketSocket.

The relevant codes are as follow:

### ViewController.h

```
#import <PocketSocket/PSWebSocket.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <PSWebSocketDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) PSWebSocket *socket;
```

### ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self initViews];
    [self initConstraints];
    [self initSocket];
}

-(void)initSocket
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://localhost:3000/cable"]];

    self.socket = [PSWebSocket clientSocketWithRequest:request];
    self.socket.delegate = self;

    [self.socket open];
}

-(void)joinChannel:(NSString *)channelName
{
    NSString *strChannel = @"{ \"channel\": \"RoomChannel\" }";

    id data = @{
                @"command": @"subscribe",
                @"identifier": strChannel
                };

    NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization  dataWithJSONObject:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSString * myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"myString= %@", myString);

    [self.socket send:myString];
}

#pragma mark - PSWebSocketDelegate Methods -

-(void)webSocketDidOpen:(PSWebSocket *)webSocket
{
    NSLog(@"The websocket handshake completed and is now open!");

    [self joinChannel:@"RoomChannel"];
}

-(void)webSocket:(PSWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message
{
    NSData *data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSString *messageType = json[@"type"];

    if(![messageType isEqualToString:@"ping"] && ![messageType isEqualToString:@"welcome"])
    {
        NSLog(@"The websocket received a message: %@", json[@"message"]);

        [self.messages addObject:json[@"message"]];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

-(void)webSocket:(PSWebSocket *)webSocket didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"The websocket handshake/connection failed with an error: %@", error);
}

-(void)webSocket:(PSWebSocket *)webSocket didCloseWithCode:(NSInteger)code reason:(NSString *)reason wasClean:(BOOL)wasClean
{
    NSLog(@"The websocket closed with code: %@, reason: %@, wasClean: %@", @(code), reason, (wasClean) ? @"YES": @"NO");
}
```

### Important Note:

I also digged a bit into the subscription class source code:

```
def add(data)
        id_key = data['identifier']
        id_options = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(id_key).with_indifferent_access

        subscription_klass = connection.server.channel_classes[id_options[:channel]]

        if subscription_klass
          subscriptions[id_key] ||= subscription_klass.new(connection, id_key, id_options)
        else
          logger.error "Subscription class not found (#{data.inspect})"
        end
      end
```

Notice the line:

```
connection.server.channel_classes[id_options[:channel]]
```

We need to use the name of the class for the channel.

The DHH youtube video uses "room_channel" for the room name but the class file for that channel is named "RoomChannel".

We need to use the class name not the instance name of the channel.

### Sending Messages

Just in case others want to know how to send messages also, here is my iOS code to send a message to the server:

```
-(void)sendMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    NSString *strMessage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{ \"action\": \"speak\", \"message\": \"%@\" }", message];

    NSString *strChannel = @"{ \"channel\": \"RoomChannel\" }";

    id data = @{
                @"command": @"message",
                @"identifier": strChannel,
                @"data": strMessage
                };

    NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization  dataWithJSONObject:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSString * myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"myString= %@", myString);

    [self.socket send:myString];
}
```

This assumes you've hooked up your UITextField to handle pressing the return key or some "send" button somewhere on your UI.

This whole demo app was a quick hack, obviously, if I was to do it in a real app, I would make my code more cleaner, more reusable and abstract it into a class altogether.

### Connecting to Rails server from real iPhone device:

In order for iPhone app to talk to Rails server on real device, not iPhone simulator.

Do the following:

1. Check your computer's TCP/IP address. On my iMac for example, it might be 10.1.1.10 on some days (can change automatically in the future if using DHCP).
2. Edit your Rail's `config > environment > development.rb` file and put in the following line somewhere like before the `end` keyword:

   `Rails.application.config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http://10.1.1.10:3000']`
3. Start your Rails server using following command:

   `rails server -b 0.0.0.0`
4. Build and run your iPhone app onto the iPhone device. You should be able to connect and send messages now :D

I got these solutions from following links:

[Request origin not allowed: http://localhost:3001 when using Rails5 and ActionCable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188892/request-origin-not-allowed-http-localhost3001-when-using-rails5-and-actionca)

[Rails 4.2 server; private and public ip not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675438/rails-4-2-server-private-and-public-ip-not-working)

Hope that helps others in the future.

Comment: Are there any considerations for unwinding these subscriptions?

Comment: If i want to disconnect, can i simply disconnect, or do i need to send ActionCable a message to properly clean this connection up?

Answer (score 4):

// open socket connection  first

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/cable");
```

// subscribe to channel
// 'i' should be in json

```
var i = { 'command': 'subscribe', 'identifier': {'channel':'ProfileChannel', 'Param_1': 'Value_1',...}};

 ws.send(i);
```

// After that you'll receive data inside the 'onmessage' function.

Cheers!

Comment: Is this Javascript or what library is WebSocket coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Here is the code snippet that i'm using to connect to action cable.

```
  function WebSocketTest()
   {
         var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/cable");
         ws.onopen = function(data)
         {
           var i = JSON.stringify({"command":"subscribe" , "identifier": JSON.stringify({"channel":"CHANNEL_NAME"})});
           // send data request
           var j =  JSON.stringify({"command":"message","identifier": JSON.stringify({"channel":"CHANNEL_NAME"}),"data": {"message":"Hello World","action": "METHOD_NAME_IN_CHANNEL","email": "abc@xyz.com",  "token" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "id": {"id_message" : "something", "ddd" : "something"}}}) 
           var response = ws.send(i);
            setTimeout(function()
            {
              var response1 = ws.send(j);
            }, 1000);
         };
         ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
         { 
            var received_msg = evt.data;
         };
      }
```

Comment: Could you share you routes please?

Comment: Hello.
I have try but is not receiving the broadcast
here is my JS


```
ws.onopen = (data) => {
    const i = JSON.stringify({
      command: 'subscribe', identifier: JSON.stringify({ channel: 'polls_channel' })
    });
    // send data request
    const response = ws.send(i); //eslint-disable-line
  };

   ws.onmessage = ((message) => {
       if (JSON.parse(message.data).type === 'change') {
         fetchPolls();
       }
   });
```

Comment: To display your receiving data, Please use the following code

 ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
            { 
              var received_msg = evt.data;
              var json_obj = JSON.parse(received_msg);
              console.log("Rcvd",json_obj["message"])
            };