# Request origin not allowed: http://localhost:3001 when using Rails5 and ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Having server issues with an app in Rails 5.0.0.beta2 trying to use ActionCable.

Using localhost:3000 works fine, as that is what most of ActionCable defaults to. But if I try to run the rails server on port 3001, it gives me `Request origin not allowed: http://localhost:3001`

The ActionCable docs mention using something like `ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins = ['http://localhost:3001']` which does work for me if I put it in `config.ru`

But that seems like a really weird place to put it. I feel like it should be able to go in an initializer file, or my development.rb environment config file.

To further prove my point that it *should* be allowed to go in there, the setting `ActionCable.server.config.disable_request_forgery_protection = true` works to ignore request origin, even when I include it in development.rb.

Why would `ActionCable.server.config.disable_request_forgery_protection` work in development.rb, but `ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins` doesn't (but does work in config.ru)?

Not a pressing issue, since I have several options as a work around. I just want to know if I'm missing something obvious about how I imagine this should be working.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can put 
`Rails.application.config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http://localhost:3001']` in your development.rb

See https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable#allowed-request-origins for more informations

Answer (score 7):

For my flutter app, request origin was nil. So, needed to add `nil` in the list.

I have added this code in `config/environments/development.rb`, and it works!

```rb
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/, /file:\/\/*/, 'file://', nil]
```

Answer (score 4):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42342140/2043736), you can also add the following code to `config/environments/development.rb` to allow requests from both `http` and `https`:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ...

  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [%r{https?://\S+}]
end
```

`config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins` accepts an array of strings or regular expressions as the [documentation states](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html):

> Action Cable will only accept requests from specified origins, which
>   are passed to the server config as an array. The origins can be
>   instances of strings or regular expressions, against which a check for
>   the match will be performed.

The regex listed below will match both `http` and `https` urls from any domain so be careful when using them. It is just a matter of preference which one to use.

- `[%r{https?://\S+}]` # Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716513/ruby-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)
- `[%r{http[s]?://\S+}]`
- `[%r{http://*}, %r{https://*}]`
- `[/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]`