# cannot connect to localhost only 127.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I'm starting my rails application now I'm unable to view the app on `localhost:3000` instead I now have to use `127.0.0.1` which theoretically is the same. But I seem to get errors because of it, such as:

```
Request origin not allowed: http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

now I ran `sudo nano /etc/hosts` to check my hosts and `localhost` is set up to be `127.0.0.1` so I'm finding this strange. The localhost just shows a blank page.

Does anybody have experience fixing this issue?

Comment: Are you using ActionCable? Perhaps this will answer? [Request origin not allowed: http://localhost:3001 when using Rails5 and ActionCable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188892/request-origin-not-allowed-http-localhost3001-when-using-rails5-and-actionca)

Comment: that seemed to fix the issue, thanks for linking :) !