# Rails ActionCable error during websocket handshake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm trying to build a messaging app with Rails 5 ActionCable, but I'm getting the above error in the JS console.

`ws://localhost:3002/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

I'm using the Redis and Puma gems.

I have a Redis server running `7937:M 24 Jul 18:20:53.379 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379`

I start the Rails server with Puma: `rails s Puma -p 3002` (is this even required?)

`config/cable.yml` looks like this...

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

When I enter `rails c` and I execute the broadcast:

```
2.2.4 :003 > ActionCable.server.broadcast("messages:1", text: "test")
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to messages:1: {:text=>"test"}
 => 0
```

...you can see it returns 0, so it fails. And the console error message looks like...

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3002/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to NGINX. Is this an NGINX issue? If so, how do I resolve it? Do I reconfigure my `nginx.conf` file in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/`? Currently it looks like this...

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**SOLUTION**

Make sure you have

`<%= action_cable_meta_tag %>`  inside `application.html.erb`

Also,

`config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:3000/cable"` inside `config/environments/development.rb`

Comment: The `action_cable_meta_tag` did it for me. Without it, the client doesn't know where to send the requests and tries a default url. Thanks.

Comment: this only works for development. how to implement at production using wss?

Answer (score 6):

put this in you environment config file

`config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]`

Comment: `<%= action_cable_meta_tag %>` inside `application.html.erb` + above config worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when i had a trailing slash in

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['https://dev-fuud8f6.firebaseapp.com/']
```

and removing it fixed the issue for me(sown below)

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['https://dev-fuud8f6.firebaseapp.com']
```

i identified this error by using [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55715218/5706413)

```
curl -v 'https://your_site.com/cable' -H 'Origin: https://your_site.com' -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Key: MIN4DsiwEAutsE11kgG5rg=='  -H 'Upgrade: websocket' -H 'Connection: Upgrade' -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13'
```

look into your server log file maybe in

> log/staging.log

[i was in staging server]