# ActionCable - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, actioncable

Have deployed my Rails 5.2 app via Capistrano, and am having problems with ActionCable. I am using Nginx, Puma and Lets Encrypt.

I have tried many combinations of configuration, but each time am receiving the same error. I am not sure *how* to debug this issue, and suggestions as well and any tips on re-arranging my ngnx.conf would be well-appreciated.

*Have changed the real website to website.com*

nginx.conf

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/website/shared/tmp/sockets/website-puma.sock;
}

server {
  server_name website.com www.website.com;
  root /home/deploy/apps/website/current/public;
  index index.html;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://puma;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  server_name website.com www.website.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

config/production.rb

```
  config.action_cable.mount_path = '/cable'
  config.action_cable.url = 'wss://website.com/cable'
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'https://website.com', 'http://website.com' ]
```

Error Message

[image]

Reviewed posts

- [Rails5 Action Cable Nginx 404 and 502 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772674/rails5-action-cable-nginx-404-and-502-errors?rq=1)
- [ActionCable on AWS: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536926/actioncable-on-aws-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code?rq=1)
- [Actioncable Nginx and Puma WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39292968/actioncable-nginx-and-puma-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response?rq=1)

**UPDATE**

Updated nginx.conf

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/immersive/shared/tmp/sockets/immersive-puma.sock;
}


  server {
    if ($host = www.immersive.ch) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = immersive.ch) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name immersive.ch www.immersive.ch;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
  }

  server {
    server_name immersive.ch www.immersive.ch;
    root /home/deploy/apps/immersive/current/public;
    index index.html;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
    location @puma {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://puma;
    }

    location /cable {
      proxy_pass http://puma;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;

      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_redirect off;
      break;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/immersive.ch/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/immersive.ch/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
  }
```

production.rb

```rb
config.action_cable.mount_path = '/cable'
config.action_cable.url = 'wss://immersive.ch/cable'
config.action_cable.allow_same_origin_as_host = true
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ '*' ]
#config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'https://immersive.ch', 'http://immersive.ch' ]
```

Partial output of curl

```
> GET /cable HTTP/1.1
> Host: immersive.ch
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: https://immersive.ch
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: MIN4DsiwEAutsE11kgG5rg==
> Upgrade: websocket
> Connection: Upgrade
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.15.5 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2019 20:10:43 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 7a9aa8f1-676d-419b-9e4f-0c1bb38bcaa2
< X-Runtime: 0.004730
<
* Connection #0 to host immersive.ch left intact
Page not found%
```

puma.rb

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
workers 2
daemonize true
plugin :tmp_restart
```

**EDIT 2**

/var/logs/nginx/access.log

```
HTTP/1.1" 200 4447 "https://immersive.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [16/Apr/2019:22:33:58 +0200] "GET /cable HTTP/1.1" 404 24 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [16/Apr/2019:22:33:59 +0200] "GET /cable HTTP/1.1" 404 24 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
```

puma.error.log

```
I, [2019-04-16T22:39:06.100106 #21136]  INFO -- : [80dc2a43-13e1-499e-a8f6-9fd54d48270b] Started GET "/cable" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2019-04-16 22:39:06 +0200
I, [2019-04-16T22:39:06.103811 #21136]  INFO -- : [80dc2a43-13e1-499e-a8f6-9fd54d48270b] Started GET "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2019-04-16 22:39
E, [2019-04-16T22:39:06.103943 #21136] ERROR -- : [80dc2a43-13e1-499e-a8f6-9fd54d48270b] Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: close, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
I, [2019-04-16T22:39:06.104062 #21136]  INFO -- : [80dc2a43-13e1-499e-a8f6-9fd54d48270b] Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2019-04-16 22:39
```

puma.access.log

```
2019-04-16 20:58: HTTP parse error, malformed request (127.0.0.1): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ActionCable answers 404 when `Origin` header is missing or does not match/invalid.

Check that it's not you regular 404:

```
curl -v 'https://your_site.com/cable' -H 'Origin: https://your_site.com' -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Key: MIN4DsiwEAutsE11kgG5rg=='  -H 'Upgrade: websocket' -H 'Connection: Upgrade' -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13'
```

When everything is fine there'll be `HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols`, on origin mismatch - just `Page not found` body, or your regular 404 page if there's some other routing trouble.

Make sure `allowed_request_origins` in settings is correct. Note that it includes port, if it's non-standard. Check which `Origin` browser sends in devtools

Also there's `config.action_cable.allow_same_origin_as_host = true` (the default, needs correct `Host` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers)

Then we need nginx to pass all the headers that are being used to reconstruct origin:

```
  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://puma;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # <- most probably this one is missing
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on; # this is default, but just to be sure

    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_redirect off;
    break;
  }
```

*Update:*

Remaining two cases when activecable responds with this is failed connection authentication and missing websocket driver(should not be the case for puma)

Comment: Awesome answer! What does ```Sec-WebSocket-Key``` mean and where does the value come from?

Comment: @ardochhigh it's part of websocket protocol handshake, browser generates it for every request to prove that connection is really websocket

Comment: Thanks for the great answer but still no luck. I will post the full nginx inc. actual sitename and output of curl.

Comment: PS, those Hasselblads are great cameras, esp. the 6x6 aspect.

Comment: @ardochhigh grep your logs for `Request origin not allowed`, also `'*'` does not match anything, use `%r{.*}` for that

Comment: Changed config to ```config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ %r{.*} ]```. - problem remains. Frustrating!

Comment: See ```Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails``` ... is it significant?

Comment: Am deploying with Capistrano ... which does not restart Nginx. All works now, after ```sudo service nginx restart``` Thanks @Vasfed