# ActionCable usage in Rails 5 RESTful API Development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, api-design, actioncable

I am trying to create a RESTful API for the first time.

Sending Request(Client to Server) and Response(Server to Client) using Action Cable.

How to send request from other Applications(like Android/iOS App, Web App'n or Desktop App'n) and give response to the application.

I have used Action Cable in normal Web Application.

Please provide me some links with guides of ActionCable usage in Rails 5 RESTful API.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to ActionCable from iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145429/connecting-to-actioncable-from-ios-app)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the detail to use Action Cable as Restful API.

1. Use following JSON for subscription.

   {
         "command": "subscribe",
         "identifier": {
           "channel": "CHANEL_NAME"
         }
       }
2. Use following JSON for model subscription.

   {
       "command": "subscribe",
       "identifier": {
        "channel": "CHANEL_NAME",
        "post_id": 1
       }
      }
3. Use following JSON to call any method in channel.

   {
    "command": "message",
    "identifier": {
    "channel": "CHANEL_NAME"
    },
    "data": {
      "action": "ACTION_NAME",
      ....
   }
   }